# python complexity calculation

Tags: python, complexity-theory, big-o

I have the following code which i have to calculate 'Big-O' of:

```
def f3(lst):
    i = len(lst)
    while i>0:
        for j in range(i):
            for k in range(j, 10**5):
                print(i)
        i -= 2
```

Assuming `lst` is a list with length n, and operations take `O(1)`, here is what I come up to:
the 2nd `for` is a constant since it iterates till 10**5 every time so we can 'ignore' it (it's like `O(1)`).

The while runs n times and the first for loop runs n/2 times so in general the complexity should be `O(n^2)`.

Is that correct? My friend think it is `O(n^4)`.

Thanks.

Comment: The second for loop is not constant, it runs from `j -> 10**5`, and `j` gets bigger each iteration.

Comment: I think it still runs a finite number of times which doesnt depend on size of the input, so it's still constant in my opinion...
(?)

Comment: But `i` is determined by the length of the input list, and `i` will dictate how large `j` gets.

Comment: I see, so can you please explain how you would go about calculating this complexity? thanks

Comment: But the 3rd for loop isn't another `*n` - its really `10**5-n`, which would be constant. I would say you are correct and that this is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I agree with Jared. O() is a matter of asymptotics, so you can consider n to be very large, and once it passes 10**5 the inner loop doesn't matter. So it should be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly established that the while loop is iterated `n/2` times. The outer `for` loop contained within is executed for `j = 1, 2, ... i`, where `i` is set to `len(lst)`, `len(lst) - 2`, ..., `1` in subsequent `while` iterations. So, the outer `for` loop is executed for `j = 1, 2, ..., len(lst)`, `j = 1, 2, ..., len(lst) - 2`, ..., `j = 1`. In total, that are `O(n^2)` iterations of the outer `for` loop. While the inner `for` loop is not executed a constant number of times, it is iterated at most `10**5` times, which *is* constant. Therefore, `O(n^2)` is a correct upper bound to the runtime of this function.

---

Here's a slightly different explanation. I hope you agree that the following code is equivalent to your code in terms of computational time:

```
def f3_simple(n):
    i = n                         
    condition = i>0               
    while condition:              
        r1 = range(i)             
        for j in r1:              
            r2 = range(j, 10**5)  
            for k in r2:          
                print(i)          
        i -= 2                    
        condition = i>0
```

Here's the same code, with annotations:

```
def f3_simple(n):
    i = n                         # "length": O(1)
    condition = i>0               # comparison: O(1)
    while condition:              # executed O(n) times per function call
        r1 = range(i)               # range(i): O(i)
        for j in r1:                # executed O(n) times per WHILE iteration
            r2 = range(j, 10**5)      # range(j, 10**5): O(10**5 - j) = O(1)
            for k in r2:              # executed O(1) times per OUTER FOR iteration
                print(i)                # print: O(1)
        i -= 2                      # decrement: O(1)
        condition = i>0             # comparison: O(1)
```

Therefore, the total runtime is indeed `O(n^2)`.

Comment: the problem with this is that j will be "stuck" if/when it is over 10**5 and then the program wont even go into the 2nd for and that changes the runtime doesnt it?
for any i>10**5 there would be a finite number of operations so in total isnt it supposed to be O(n) ?

Comment: @user2263215: No. The reason is that to even detect that the loop is iterated not at all, you need to check the condition once, which takes `O(1)`. Thus, the complexity is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: could you please respond to "ORBOT Inc."'s question below?
I had the same thought a day ago.

Comment: @user2263215: I tried to do so with the second part of the answer. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the answer O(n^3) ? Because the inner loop is still taking runtime for checking the condition therefor linear function of j since a certain place, therefore a sum of j by i by n which is O(n^3) ?